# Can Apache Jena support soft deletion?

Tags: jena

Can Apache Jena support soft deletion?

Comment: It's marking entities (I'll be vague there ;-) as deleted, rather than removing them from a database. Lots of `thing.deleted is false` in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that what you mean by *soft deletion* is that triples remain in the model but are not returned by API calls or SPARQL queries, then, no, there's no support for that in Jena. What I would do, in this circumstance, is keep a separate model for "deleted" triples to be stored in, so that you can add them back during an 'undelete' operation. The only thing to be careful of in this context is b-nodes. Also, note that the only thing you *can* delete from a Jena model is a triple: if you are thinking in terms of the resources in your model, to delete them you need to remove all of the triples that mention that model.

If that's not what you mean by soft deletion, you'll need to say more.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Since I think real deletion resource in Jena model involve high-overhead than mark them as unavailable, my requirement needs to delete & add resource frequently. Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Removing a resource from a Jena model may not involve high overhead: it depends which model you are using (and whether you are using inference). I would advise doing some empirical performance tests using a setup close to your intended application architecture before making assumptions about what will or will not be performant. By the way, if this answer satisfies your original query, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the tick mark.